# Intelligent Eclipse auto import?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

With generic class names such `Document`, `Element` or `Query`, the Eclipse import helper returns many candidates and it takes a long time to select the right one.

Can I modify the behaviour somehow so that for example when I already have 3 Lucene imports, `org.apache.lucene.Query` is shown on top of `javax.management.Query`?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of control+shift+o keys can list all the possible import options of the particular package.

Comment: That is what I ment with "Eclipse import helper".